# Computer doesn't start after installing new Corsair DDR2 RAM

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I have a new memory stick (*CORSAIR 2 GB of RAM*) and I have an older set of 2 sticks of RAM that are 512MB and 256 MB. (I bought it 1GB actually but the Computer tells that it has 256MB of RAM only).

I bought a new one and that is the CORSAIR 2 GB. When I put it on the DIMM Slot and start the PC, nothing happened. I just received a long 1 beep.

Then I installed the older RAM and it is turning back on. I try to update my BIOS, reset everything, then it still doesn't work at all.

I have a K8M800 Micro Motherboard with an AM2 Dual Core Processor. Can anyone help me get this other RAM working?

Comment: sounds like your computer does not support 2GB modules.  We need specific hardware information and you need to tell us what the beep code means for us.

Answer (score 3):

The Biostar [K8M800](http://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=141) you mention only supports up to 2 GB of memory in 1 GB modules.  (You can look up what any motherboard/system supports using tools at crucial.com or any of the other memory vendors).

If you want to investigate a bit further, if you know what BIOS your system is running, you could look up what the [beep code means](http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Actually your RAM will not show in full if not supported by motherboard. Go to your motherboard manufacturer site, and check how much RAM is supported by it.

For example, I have 4 GB RAM. But it shows only 3.2 GB. Because I use 32 bit OS. If I wanna use 4 GB, I have to use 64 bit OS.

So, you installed 1 GB, but it will behave like 256.

And the new RAM, you wanna try to install, is not compatible with your motherboard. When you insert it, your RAM slot can't detect the new RAM. That's why you hear just a long beep. And normally, without RAM, your PC can't run.

There is only one costly but better solution - UPGRADE THE WHOLE SYSTEM. :)